# How to use if/else and responseJson in componentDidMount?

Tags: react-native

I have a `componentDidMount` and I want to show some data by `listView`. Now I want to check is there any data exist or not, so I check that by an `if/else` but it's not working and always `if` is true.

I put a `log.console` in `componentDidMount` to show `responseJson` and now that show `none`.

But When I have some other data like products `if` is `true` **again**.

```
  componentDidMount(){

    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const cat = navigation.getParam('cat');
    fetch('products.php',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-type':'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        cat:cat
      })
    }).then((response)=>response.json()).
    then((responseJson)=>{
      console.log(responseJson);
      if (responseJson=='none') {
        this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          empty:true,
        });
      }else{
        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2)=>r1!=r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson)
        });
      }
    }).done();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing your code it seems that you want to check for responseJson is empty or not. If it is empty then setState to empty else setState with response data.

first of all, never apply to check on whole object as you have done

`if (responseJson=='none') {`

instead of this you can do check on error that come along with data.

```
if (responseJson.error === true) {
       this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          empty:true,
        });
      }else{
        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2)=>r1!=r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson)
        });
}
```

or you can apply check on data

```
if (responseJson.data === null) {
       this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          empty:true,
        });
      }else{
        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2)=>r1!=r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson)
        });
}
```

Comment: responseJson.error ?? I have no error. I have two response. 1: Json data. 2: none. none is a string and printed by php.